# header's structure of .7z files?

Tags: header, compression, 7zip, rar

Looking up in net I could find a general overview of rar format structure.
http://www.rarlab.com/technote.htm

But what would I be glad to be informed is how 7z files are segmented block by block.

thanks.

Comment: i found this but cudnt understand it http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BJOERN/Compress-Deflate7-0.9/7zip/DOC/7zFormat.txt

Comment: What's the problem specifically? That documents seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: explain it to me plz , byte per byte . your answer would be benefic not just for me but to all people who frequent stackforums.

Answer (score 6):

Refer to the [DOC/7zFormat.txt](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/BJOERN/Compress-Deflate7-1.0/7zip/DOC/7zFormat.txt) file in the source distribution (an updated version can be found in the official SDK: https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).

http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/7z

To get a better understanding of the file format, you can use [hachoir-wx](https://github.com/vstinner/hachoir) (needs installed wxPython) to navigate an archive to the bit level. It is available via [pip](https://pypi.org/project/hachoir/). Their parser supports 7zip among lots of other file formats.

Comment: i dont know how to use this , besides , i want to know where the encryption system byte flag is located , how is it encoded , and so the compression method , and the segment where the packed file is deployed in.

Comment: I came across this issue because I want to parse 7zip headers with node js. Thank you for hinting to `hachoir`, that is a really, really helpful tool!

Comment: Be aware that the linked document is ancient (2010). You can get the newest documentation from https://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html. It's inside the DOC folder.